# How can I send raw postscript to a remote printer via CUPS?

Tags: cups, printing

I have an ancient fax device with a printer interface that only accepts postscript level 1 documents formatted in a specific way. I only have access to this printer over the lpd:// protocol.

I have some old documents from our previous system that work fine on our Unix machines, but they are altered somehow by CUPS when I use lp on our Linux system. The PDF files that end up in the print queue are significantly modified versions of the original, and although they still render in ghostscript, they don't do anything on the printer.

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell CUPS "don't process this, just send it to the printer without modification", or whether there's a lpd client or procedure I could try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell it to send RAW using the following command:

```
lp -d printer_name -o raw filename
```

-o lets you specify an option. In this case, it specifies no PPD to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the printer administration tool on my system (Fedora 12) I was able to add a "Generic" "PostScript Level 1 Printer". You may be able to do the same there.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using that generic driver. For some reason it reformats the postscript document between lp and the remote print spool (I am assuming this is CUPS' doing).